# FirebaseApp.configure() has an error use of unresolved identifier 'FirebaseApp'

Tags: xcode, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-storage

So every time in my pod file I decide to add something like pod 'Firebase/Storage’ with pod 'Firebase/Core’, in my app delicate `FirebaseApp.configure()` has an error use of unresolved identifier 'FirebaseApp' my pod file is

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U7s5StRuNrI_2WtpHSvHhwhA1TMCsQ255dnjDAEhhcE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 75):

I solved this problem by using FirebaseCore instead of Firebase library:

```
import FirebaseCore
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44753265/firebaseapp-configure-has-an-error-use-of-unresolved-identifier-firebaseapp/63089370#63089370. Firebase made a fix in the 6.31.1 version.

Answer (score 15):

Your appdelegate class should look like this:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FIRApp.configure()
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }
}
```

I am assuming you are using xcode 8 and swift 3.

Comment: No problem, we can simply convert it to swift 2.2

Comment: so how would it look it with the conversion? (this is stressing me out)

Comment: Don't worry, I am updating the answer, Although I think it is still the same thing except in the swift 2.2 app delegate

Comment: tried it with only 'Firebase/Core’ (the only thing i can put in without errors) and FIRApp.configure() didn't worked but FirebaseApp.configure() worked just fine

Comment: So you imported firebase and FirebaseApp.configure() is working? Can you please show us your app delegate.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1atTuu4d3yy2QxW-8O8t15C_W5QS7rgntQJRAmvNovWg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Maybe you are getting the wrong version of firebase. Add this to your podfile. Your app delegate looks right. `pod 'FirebaseCore'`

Comment: when i do this i now get to error no such module firebase and i updated my pods so I'm good

Comment: you know what I'm going to follow the exact steps on the website and see if it makes a difference compared to how i normally do it

Comment: alright I'm doing good so far but confused on this part 2. Configure a FIRApp shared instance, typically in your application's application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method:

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xH9ULIXwY8vU6JIL_cR4CXrpRoPD1WQyiAeWYoA27Ok/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Use this `FirebaseApp.configure()
` or `FIRApp.configure()`. Which ever works.

Comment: FirebaseApp.configure() is the only one that works and the problem is whenever i want to add other pods besides 'Firebase/Core’ the error with FirebaseApp.configure() shows up and the error is use of unresolved identifier 'FirebaseApp'

Comment: idk if it as to do with this but all frameworks are red (besides the one in Linked Frameworks and libraries), .xctest is also red.

Answer (score 7):

In my case was because I was using an older version of Firebase (3.11.1)

```
pod repo update
pod update
```

After update my repo and my local specs repositories with Firebase (4.2.0) FirebaseApp was resolved by Xcode!

Comment: Thanks for this. I followed current (03/09/2019) Firebase docs and the FirebaseApp.configure() did not work.  Then I ran the commands you showed and I saw (Installing Firebase 5.18.0 (was 3.10.0)).  Not sure why the initial pod installation installs that older version at the current date.  After the update FirebaseApp.configure() did indeed work.

Answer (score 6):

Run `pod update` to at least Firebase 6.31.1.

Firebase made a change in 6.28.0 that exposed an Xcode build race condition. The change was reverted in 6.31.1. Details at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6341

Comment: Thanks Man... that worked for me! After following your steps I was able to use import Firebase only without need to upgrade to FirebaseCore

Answer (score 4):

Try pod 'Firebase' instead of pod 'Firebase/Core'

And check if Firebase 4.x was installed after 'pod install'

Answer (score 2):

use "import FirebaseCore" , instead of "import Firebase"

Answer (score 1):

This will resolve this

```
 sudo gem install cocoapods 
 pod update
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution by **morganchen12** at this [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/271#issuecomment-300313026) comment resolved the same issue for me. I needed to modify the Podfile for the unit tests (OP already completed), and then add Firebase to the Header Search paths.

For preservation, the comment is:

> The issue is caused by duplicate FIRApp class definitions in the test runtime.
>
> Your Podfile should look like this:
>
> ```
> target "FirebaseDemo" do
>   install_pods
>
>   target "FirebaseDemoTests" do
>     inherit! :search_paths
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> In order to avoid the missing required module Firebase error, add "${PODS_ROOT}/Firebase/Core/Sources" to the end of your test target's Header Search Paths in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

My pod file has Firebase/Core and Firebase/Auth.

updating the pod didn't solve it for me and I also tried pod 'Firebase'.
[It was simply this mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69785993/10737396)